# How to avoid the proceed to checkout page in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

> I wanted to know that how can i remove the cart page? it always
>   showing proceed to checkout.after add to cart i do want to show the
>   checkout page not the cart page is it possible with magento?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to disable the redirect to cart page after adding product to cart then,

Goto Magento Backend

> System » Configuration » Checkout » Shopping Cart

and set "**After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart**" to "**No**"

Else if you wish to by pass the cart page completely and head directly to checkout page, you will need to overload the controller, you can override the **addAction** function in the **CartController** of the **Mage/Checkout** module. This is located in **app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php**

browse the link for the same
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller